# Cocoa/Obj-C - TextField to clipboard button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, clipboard

Got 1 **UITextField** and 1 button.
There is text in my textfield, and when we click on the button, the text is copied to the **OSX clipboard.**

How can I do that?
I've readed the **NSPastboard** Class Reference but didn't understand how to do that -simply-

Got my button defined in my **AppControler.h** like this:

```
- (IBAction)copyButton:(id)sender;
```

What am I supposed to write in my **AppControler.m**? My textfield is called "descTextField"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)copyButton:(id)sender {
   NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
   [pasteBoard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSStringPboardType, nil] owner:nil];
   [pasteBoard setString: [textField stringValue] forType:NSStringPboardType];
}
```

Comment: error: request for member 'text' in something not a structure or union

Comment: what is the class of the textField?

Comment: If this is NSTextField then use [textField stringValue]

Answer (score 0):

according to [apple's doc / guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/PasteboardGuide106.pdf) i think it should be rather like this:

```
- (IBAction)copyButton:(id)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]; 
    [pasteBoard clearContents];
    [pasteBoard writeObjects:@[[textField stringValue]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
    - (IBAction)copyToClipboardActionBtn:(id)sender {
        UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pasteBoard setString: _descTextField.text];
    }
```